# Order of cyclic groups

Tags: number-theory, abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group) says:

> It is known that $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is cyclic if and only if n is 1 or 2 or 4 or $p^k$ or $2p^k$ for an odd prime number p and k ≥ 1.

The statement seems provable given the definition and properties of the [Carmichael function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function).

I need a reference (preferably a book) to read more on cyclic group, their order, and the Carmichael function. I tried several book (on number theory or algebra), but I couldn't find one that stated and proved the above theorem.

Could you please recommend one?

Comment: You've got it backwards. The properties of the Carmichael function are provable because of this theorem.

Comment: Thanks @Qiaochu. I didn't know that.

Comment: I also found [The Theory of Numbers](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/13693/13693-pdf.pdf) Chapter 5 "Primitive Roots Modulo m" (by Carmichael himself) worth reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also Theorem 2.41 in **An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers** (5th Edition) by Niven, Zuckerman, and Montgomery. The proof does not require Carmichael's function, though they do use Euler's totient function, defining a primitive root to be an element of multiplicative order $\phi(m)$ modulo $m$.

They first prove every prime $p$ has $\phi(p-1)$ primitive roots modulo $p$ (Theorem 2.36). Later, they show that if $p$ is a prime, then there are $\phi(\phi(p^2))$ primitive roots modulo $p^2$ (Theorem 2.39). Theorem 2.40 proves that if $p$ is an odd prime and $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p^2$, then $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha\geq 2$. Then a discussion deals with the case of $p=2$, showing there are no primitive roots modulo $2^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha\geq 3$; finally, the composite numbers that are not prime powers nor twice prime powers are dealt with.

Answer (score 4):

As Qiaochu points out, while the Carmichael function indicates how much the multiplicative group fails to be cyclic (when it is less than Euler's totient function), the characterization of those $n > 1$ for which the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is cyclic was done first.

The result is given in Gauss's Disquisitiones Arithmeticae, articles 52-56 and 82-89, although that precedes the terminology of groups and is thus framed in terms of congruence classes of integers and [primitive roots modulo n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n): "In Article 56 [Gauss] states that Lambert and Euler knew of them, but that his is the first rigorous demonstration that they exist."  The Wikipedia article [Multiplicative group of integers modulo n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) gives a sketch of a modern proof using the prime powers factorization of n and the corresponding factorization of the group of units.

Once it has been worked out which prime powers n have cyclic multiplicative groups, the crux of the proof is that a product of two cyclic groups is cyclic if and only if their orders are coprime.

Answer (score 3):

Ireland, Rosen: A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory

Answer (score 3):

For full proofs, see [p. 275, Theorem 9.3.5](http://books.google.com/books?id=iJx1lP9ZcIkC&pg=PA275) in Bach; Shallit. *Algorithmic Number Theory*.

Answer (score 2):

Hardy and Wright. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/MildorfNT.pdf gives a proof in section 4.

Comment: That has the cyclicity proofs but nothing on Carmichael's function.

Answer (score 2):

See Chapter 4 of  LeVeque's [Fundamentals of Number Theory](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486689069.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the citation for an excellent little paper from the MAA's *Mathematics Magazine* that takes an algebraic approach to this problem:

> David R. Guichard. When is $U(n)$
>   cyclic? An algebraic approach.
>   *Mathematics Magazine* 72(2) (1999), 139-142.

Here's a [link](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2690598) to this article on JSTOR.

Comment: I wonder what would constitute a *non-algebraic* approach to the cyclicity of the unit group?  (Edit: I clicked through to the first page of the article and apparently "algebraic" is being contrasted with "number theoretic".  As an algebraic number theorist I am less than thrilled by this proposed dichotomy.)

Comment: @Pete L. Clark: The proof that $n$ has a primitive root if and only if $n = 1, 2, 4, p^k$ or $2p^k$ for some odd prime $p$ and positive integer $k$ involves only elementary number theory.  And $U(n)$ is cyclic if and only if $n$ has a primitive root.

Comment: sure, but is elementary number theory not algebraic?  You can study it without having studied any abstract algebra, but nevertheless it is still a part of algebra.  (And of course there are also proofs that are openly algebraic: see e.g. http://math.uga.edu/~pete/4400primitiveroots.pdf.)