# Some problem of isomophism

Tags: group-theory

Is $U(2^{n})$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_{2}} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z_{2^{n-2}}}$ if $n\geq3$?

And is $U(p^{n})$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_{p^{n}-p^{n-1}}}$ where $p$ an odd prime?

I'm really wondering about its ***proof.***

It's not my homework. I used this fact when doing my homework. I don't have to prove this fact for my homework. This question is just for curiosity.

Comment: Related to and possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42755/order-of-cyclic-groups.

Comment: @Kim Hee yeon: I have merged your unregistered account with your registered account ([this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/14654/)). If you encounter any further trouble logging in, please let one of the moderators know (via a post on [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/), or via a comment)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the well-known [structure theorem for units in modular rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Structure). Almost all number theory books contain a proof. See, for instance, Chapter 4 of  LeVeque's [Fundamentals of Number Theory](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486689069.html).