# Theorems on Primitive Roots

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

Let g be a primitive root modulo $p$($p$ is an odd prime) with $g^{p-1}\ncong{1}\ (mod\ p^{2})$. I am interested in proving that

$$g^{(p-1)p^{m-2}}\ncong{1}\ (mod\ p^{m})$$ for every $m\geq{2}$

So far, I have proven that $a^{p^{m}-p^{m-1}}\equiv{1}\ (mod\ p^{m})$ given that $gcd(a,p)=1$. If that might be of help...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332760/prove-that-a-primitive-root-of-p2-is-also-a-primitive-root-of-pn-for-n1

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I'm sorry, but it is not immediately clear to me, how this is relevant

Comment: From the given condition, $g$ is a primitive root $\pmod{p^2}$ . It is sufficient to establish $g$ is a primitive root $\pmod{p^m}$