# Prove that if g is a primitive root modulo p (p is an odd prime), then g belongs to h modulo $p^m$, where $h=(p-1)p^r$ for some r.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

Prove that if g is a primitive root modulo p (p is an odd prime), then g belongs to h modulo $p^m$, where $h=(p-1)p^r$ for some r.

I know if $g^k \equiv a\pmod{p}$, then $g^k \equiv a\pmod{p^m}$, but how can i get $h=(p-1)p^r$?

Comment: What does "belong to $\;h\pmod {p^m}\;$" mean, anyway?

Comment: I'm guessing that you mean $h$ to be the order of $g$ modulo $p^m$, and that the $r$ in your second line is no relation to the $r$ in your first line (though I'm not sure what it refers to).  Could you clarify?

Comment: @DonAntonio it is defined that if h is the smallest positive integer such that  $g^h\equiv1\pmod{p}$ we say g belongs to exponent h modulo p

Comment: @universalset the "r" is "g".... It's a typo, thx for pointing out

Comment: @walterudoing, so it looks like I was correcting in guessing that "belongs to exponent $h$ modulo $p$" is just another way of saying "has order $h$ modulo $p$".

Answer (score 2):

We can prove something more generic.

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231350/number-of-consecutive-zeros-at-the-end-of-11100-1/231374#231374), if ord$\displaystyle _{p^s}a=d,$  ord$\displaystyle _{p^{s+1}}a=d$ or $p\cdot d$ where $p$ is odd prime and ord$_na$ is the [multiplicative order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of $a\pmod n$

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that, for $g$ a primitive root modulo $p$, the order of $g$ modulo $p^m$ is of the form $(p-1)p^r$ for some $r$. Here are hints for two approaches:

(1) Prove that if $g$ has order $k$ modulo $p^m$, then it has either order $k$ or order $pk$ modulo $p^{m+1}$ (perhaps by writing out $g^k$ modulo $p^{m+1}$ and using the binomial theorem).  Now use induction on $m$ to get your result.

(2) Show that the order of $g$ modulo $p^m$ is divisible by $p-1$ and then observe that it must divide $(p-1)p^{m-1}$ by Lagrange's theorem (or your favorite specialization thereof).

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly...the problem says we have $g^{\phi{m}}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, and we need to get $g^h\equiv 1\pmod{p^m}$.

Comment: I understand that $p-1|g^{\phi(m)}$, but how does it relate to $p^r$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $g \in \Bbb Z^{+}$ without loss of generality. If $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$, then $(g,p)=1$. Hence $(g, p^{m})=1$. Suppose $g$ belongs to $h$ modulo $p^{m}$, where $h \in \Bbb Z^{+}$. Hence $g^{h} \equiv 1 \text{ (mod } p^{m})$. It follows that $p^{m}|g^{h}-1$.  Hence 
$$\; \; p^{m}q=p(p^{m-1}q)$$
$$=pq'$$
$$\quad \; \; \, =g^{h}-1 \text{},$$
where $q,q'\in \Bbb Z^{+}$. Hence $g^{h} \equiv  1 \text{ (mod } p)$. But $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$. Thus $\phi(p)|h$, or
$$h=\phi(p)s$$
$$\qquad \, =(p-1)s \text{,}$$
where $s \in \Bbb Z^{+}$. Note
$$h| \phi(p^{m}) \text{,}$$
or equivalently, $h|p^{m-1}(p-1)$. Hence 
$$p^{m-1}(p-1)=ht \qquad\text{ (}t \in \Bbb Z^{+} \text{)}$$
$$\qquad \; \; =(p-1)st \text{.}$$
It follows that $p^{m-1}=st$. As the only positive divisors of $p^{m-1}$ are $1,p,p^{2},...,p^{m-1}$, we have $$s,t \in \{1,p,p^{2},...,p^{m-1}\} \text{.}$$
Let $s=p^{r}$ $(0 \le r \le m-1)$ to complete the proof.