# How many zeroes would be there at the end of $11^{(5!)!}-1$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, exponentiation, factorial

$$11-1=10 \\
121-1=120 \\
1331-1=1330$$

Now it can be seen that the tens digit increases by 1 at each increment of exponent. So, only in case of $11^{10}$ the tens digit is zero and the units digit will  be $1$. So, total $2$ zeros at the end. After that at each power increment of $10$ the occurence of 0 will shift until $11^{20}$. So, number of zeroes should be $2$. Because $(5!)!$ is a multiple of 10.

On second thought:
Is it like tens place 0 has a cyclicity of 10; hundreth place has 10^2; thousand place 10^3......Now 120! has 28 number of 10s. So, the tens and hundredth place will have zero. But the thousand place will not. So total 3 trailing zeros. Is my understanding ok?

But the answer given is $1$.

Comment: Dig a bit deeper! You noticed that $11^{10}$ ends  $..a01$ for some digit $a$. +1 for experimenting this yourself. But what about $11^{20}$, $11^{30}$ et cetera? What about $11^{100}$?

Comment: 11^11 will be similar to 11. And it will be a cycle, I think.

Comment: Yes, you are correct in that the tens digit becomes $0$ for every tenth power, and repeats in a cycle of length ten. Now turn your attention to the hundreds digit. To that end it is convenient that you only look at the powers of the form $11^{10n}$, where you already know that the tens digit is equal to zero.

Comment: See : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231350/number-of-consecutive-zeros-at-the-end-of-11100-1

Comment: So $11^{10}=25937424601$ ending with $601$. Why is this suffcient information to decide the last three digits of $11^{20}$?

Comment: What is your answer? I have checked with 11^100. I think the remainder obtained when 11^100 is divided by 100 is 01. So, it matches the idea.@Jyrki Lahtonen yes you are right. It is not sufficient. @lab bhattacherjee its ok to use binomial but what is the answer to my question?

Comment: @archangel89, $1+$(due to $10$) the number of zeros in $120!$

Comment: Is it like tens place 0 has a cyclicity of 10; hundreth place has 10^2; thousand place 10^3......Now 120! has 28 number of 10s. So, the tens and hundredth place will have zero. But the thousand place will not. So total 3 trailing zeros. Is my understanding ok?

Comment: @ user2345215 can you help me with this question?

Comment: @  lab bhattacharjee Are you sure you are talking about trailing zeroes?