# Cleverly finding Primitive Roots

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primitive-roots

From Number Theory we have the theorem that:

> There are primitive roots mod $n$ if and only if $n = 1,2,4,p^k, 2p^k$, where $p$ is an odd prime.

The question is, for such general $n$ given as above (with $n \neq p$), how does one find primitive roots without having to brute-force? Perhaps the Chinese Remainder Theorem is relevant? I'm excluding the case $n=p$ because it already has a well-written answer [Finding a primitive root of a prime number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124408/finding-a-primitive-root-of-a-prime-number/133720#133720) .

Comment: Well I doubt that there might be a way to figure out a primitive root of an integer, but I remember sometimes back in my olympiad training my teacher told us this is some kind of brute force training in early college, some of his cases were $625$ and $2401$. Regarding Chinese Remainder Theorem, i don't think it is that relevant, because you only have one modulo to consider, but you may comment your opinion down here.

Comment: [If $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$, then $g$ or $g+p$ is a primitive root modulo every power of $p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2936513/how-to-prove-that-g-or-gp-is-a-primitive-root-modulo-pa-for-a-primitive)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Great answer! Is there an easy way I can take care of the case $2p^k$?

Comment: [If $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p^k$, then either $g$ or $g + p^k$   is a primitive root modulo $2p^k$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Finding_primitive_roots)

Comment: Wow, that's a strong statement. Can I find a proof/reference somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who commented! From the comments, the answer can be found:

For $n = p^k$, firstly find a primitive root modulo $p$ as in [Finding a primitive root of a prime number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124408/finding-a-primitive-root-of-a-prime-number/133720#133720). Then, use that if $g$ is a primitive root mod $p$, then $g$ or $g+p$ is a primitive root mod $p^k$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$. Then for $n = 2p^k$, denoting by $g'$ the primitive root for $p^k$, either $g'$ or $g'+p^k$ is a primitive root mod $2p^k$.

But if anyone wants to post their own methods or proofs of the propositions used (I actually don't know the proofs), please do so!