# Prove that for prime $p \gt 2$, $(p - 1)^{p - 1} \equiv p+1 \pmod{p^2}$.

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, cyclic-groups

Prove that for prime $p \gt 2$, $(p - 1)^{p - 1} \equiv p+1 \pmod{p^2}$

**My work**

In

[At least one well-defined cyclic subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/{p^2}\mathbb{Z})^\times$, for prime $p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3793036/432081)

I examined the generators $[pq + 1], \text{where 0 } \lt q \lt p$. This cyclic group appears to be subgroup of a larger cyclic group generated by $[p-1]$.

I convinced myself that the title question is true using [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=p%20%3D%2059%3B%20%20calculate%20%28p-1%29%5E%28p-1%29%20%28mod%20p%5E2%29%20), but a proof along with some elaboration of the group theory underpinnings would be of interest.

I would have attempted to develop this further but feel I am missing something since these investigations are not generating any interest - any comments to set me on the right path will be appreciated.

Comment: and so also $(p - 1)^{p} \equiv -1 \pmod{p^2}$

Comment: and one can easily prove that for prime $p \gt 2$, the order of $[p - 1]$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/{p^2}\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is equal to $2p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

As $p-1$ is even,
$$(p-1)^{p-1}=(1-p)^{p-1}$$

Use Binomial Expansion

$$(1-p)^{p-1}\equiv1-\binom{p-1}1p\equiv1-(p-1)p\equiv?\pmod{p^2}$$