# Is there any primitive root of $p$ which is not primitive root of $p^2$ without $1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primitive-roots

Is there any primitive root of $p$ which is not primitive root of $p^2$ without $1$ (since $1$ is a primitive root of $2$ but $1$ is not a primitive root of $4$)?

Are there other examples?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227199/order-of-numbers-modulo-p2/229918#229918

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A055578 and https://oeis.org/A060503

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is a primitive root modulo $p$, then $a^p$ is also a primitive root modulo
$p$ but not modulo $p^2$.