# Proof using equation that if P an odd prime then there is a primitive root of p^n

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

I am currently studying Number Theory at the undergraduate level. In my textbook, I have come across the following question:

Show that if p is an odd prime and n is a positive integer, then there is a primitive root of $p^n$. Hint: suppose g is a primitive root of $p^k$. Use the equation we proved in problem 4* to show that either g or g+p is a primitive root of p<sup>k+1</sup>.

*equation 4 is: (g+p)<sup>$\Phi$($p^k$)</sup> $\equiv$  g<sup>$\Phi$($p^k$)</sup> - $p^k$g<sup>$\Phi$($p^k$)-1</sup> (mod p<sup>k+1</sup>).

I am completely lost on this problem, so any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: There is another piece of important information in this context: if $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p^k$, so that the order of $g$ modulo $p^k$ equals $p^{k-1}(p-1)$, then the order of $g$ modulo $p^{k+1}$ equals either $p^{k-1}(p-1)$ or $p^k(p-1)$. Do you see why this statement is true? Do you see how it can be used in conjunction with equation 4 to establish the statement you wrote?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227199/order-of-numbers-modulo-p2