# Why 5 and 5+23=28 cannot both be primitive roots mod 23^2

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I know how to show the first three parts, but I definitely have no idea about the fourth part. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry for forgetting to put the first three parts. 1. show 5 is a primitive root mod 23. 2. find the number of primitive roots mod 23. 3. find all primitive roots mod 23, and I know how to do these parts.

Comment: I presume because one of them solves $x^{22}\equiv1\pmod{23^2}$.

Comment: solved it, thanks.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227199/order-of-numbers-modulo-p2

Comment: @JohnnyWong:  could post your solution as an answer?