# Solving $25^n + 16^n \equiv 1 \pmod{121}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Original Question: Solve for all positive integers $n$ such that $25^n + 16^n \equiv 1 \pmod{121}$.

---

I began by substituting $k=2n$ to obtain $$5^k + 4^k \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$$

Considering this modulo $11$, it can be found that $k \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$. Then, I observed that $5^3 \equiv 4 \pmod{121}$, and so I split the congruence into three cases:

Case-1

> $k \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$. Then, $k=3r$. $$(4^k)^3+4^k \equiv 1 \pmod{121}$$
> It follows that $4^k \equiv 64 \pmod{121}$.

Case-2

> $k \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$. Then, $k=3r+1$. $$4 \cdot (4^r)^3 +5 \cdot (4^r) \equiv 1 \pmod{121}$$
> It follows that $4^k \equiv 37 \pmod{121}$.

Case-3

> $$k \equiv 2 \pmod{3}.$$ Then,$$ k=3r+2.$$ $$16 \cdot (4^r)^3 +25 \cdot (4^r) \equiv 1 \pmod{121}.$$ It follows that $4^r \equiv 80 \pmod{121}$.

This leaves the congruences:

- $4^k \equiv 64 \pmod{121}$ for $k \equiv 4 \pmod{15}$
- $4^k \equiv 37 \pmod{121}$ for $k \equiv 9 \pmod{15}$
- $4^k \equiv 80 \pmod{121}$ for $k \equiv 14 \pmod{15}$

From here, I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Please clarify if you seek any solution method for the quoted congruence, or only solutions using your method. If the former then the title should be changed to the quoted congruence.

Comment: @BillDubuque Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $5^3\equiv4\pmod{121},$

$$p(n)=5^{2n}+4^{2n}\equiv5^{2n}+(5^3)^{2n}\pmod{121}$$

Let's verify $5^{2n}+5^{6n}\pmod{11}$

As $5^2\equiv3\pmod{11},5^3\equiv15\equiv4,5^5\equiv3\cdot4\equiv1,$

$p(n)=5^{2n}+5^{6n}\equiv5^n(1+5^n)\pmod{11}$ and it will have  a period of $5$

$p(1)\equiv5(1+6)\not\equiv1\pmod{11}$

$p(2)\equiv5^2(1+5^2)\equiv3(1+3)\equiv1\implies n=5m+2$ where $m$ is a non-negative integer

$5^3\equiv4\pmod{121},5^5\equiv5^2\cdot4\not\equiv1\pmod{11^2}$

Using [Order of numbers modulo $p^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227199/order-of-numbers-modulo-p2), modulo ord$_{121}5=11\cdot5\  \ \ \  (1)$

$p(5m+2)=5^{2(5m+2)}+4^{2(5m+2)}\equiv5^4\cdot(5^{10})^m+4^4\cdot(4^{10})^m$

$5^4\equiv5\cdot4\pmod{121},5^5\equiv4\cdot5^2\equiv-21,5^{10}\equiv(-21)^2\equiv1+77$

As using binomial theorem  $(1+77)^m=1+\binom m177^1+$terms divisible by $77^2,$

$\implies5^4\cdot(5^{10})^m\equiv20(1+77)^m\equiv20(1+77m)\pmod{121}\equiv20+88m$

Similarly, $4^4\cdot(4^{10})^m\equiv14(1-11)^m\equiv14(1-11m)\pmod{121}\equiv14-33m$

$\implies p(5m+2)\equiv34+55m$

So, we need $$34+55m\equiv1\pmod{121}\iff55m\equiv-33\pmod{121}\iff5m\equiv-3\pmod{11}$$

As $5\cdot2\equiv-1\pmod{11}\implies5^{-1}\equiv-2$

$\implies m\equiv(-3)(-2)\pmod{11}\implies m=11r+6$

$\implies n=5(11r+6)+2\equiv32\pmod{55}$ by $(1)$

Answer (score 4):

Note that $121=11^2$, so the Euler indicator function $\varphi$ for $11^2$ is $$
\varphi(121)=
\varphi(11^2)=
\left(1-\frac 1{11}\right)\cdot 11^2=10\cdot 11=110\ .
$$
The numbers $16=4^2$, $25=5^2$ are relatively prime to $121$, so their multiplicative orders modulo $121$ are divisors of $55$, since they are already squares. So $n_0$ is a solution if and only if all $n$ of the shape $n_0+55k$ are solutions.

The congruence
$$
25^n+16^n\equiv 1\qquad\text{ modulo }11
$$
has - as mentioned - solutions of the shape $n\equiv 2$ modulo $5$.

It is thus sufficient to check all $n$ from $0$ to $54$, and among them only those which are two modulo five. So we check the eleven numbers $n$ among $2, 7,12,17,22,27,32,37,42,47, 52$. For them we compute, with equality (considered in the ring $\Bbb Z/121$) written instead of equivalence (in $\Bbb Z$) some powers, and sums of them. Because of $25^{11}=3$, $16^{11}=3^3$, it is useful to observe that $3$ has multiplicative order five, $3^5=243=242+1=1$, to the powers of $3$ are $3^0=1$, $3^1=3$, $3^2=9$, $3^3=27$, $3^4=81=-40$. We compute:
$$
\begin{aligned}
5^3 &=125 =4=2^2\ ,\\
2^7 &= 128 =7\ ,\\[3mm]
25^3 &= 5^6 = (5^3)^2=125^2=4^2=16\ ,\\
16^{37} &= (25^3)^{37}=25^{111}=25^{110+1}=25^{\varphi(121)+1}=25\ ,\\
25^{11} &= 5^{22}=(5^3)^7\cdot 5=125^7\cdot 5=4^7\cdot 5=2^{14}\cdot 5
\\
&=(2^7)^2\cdot 5 = 128^2\cdot 5=7^2\cdot 5=49\cdot 5=245
\\
&=3\ ,
\\
16^{11} &=(2^4)^{11}=2^{44}=(2^7)^6\cdot 4=128^6\cdot 4=7^6\cdot 4=343^2\cdot 4=(-20)^2\cdot 4
\\
&=1600=390=27=3^3\ ,
\\
25^2 &= 625 = 20\ ,\\
16^2 &= 256 = 14\ ,
\\[4mm]
25^2 + 16^2 &= 20 + 14 = 34\ne 1\ ,\\
25^7 + 16^7 &= (5^3)^4\cdot 25 +(2^7)^4 = 4^4\cdot 25+7^4 =7\cdot 2\cdot 25+7\cdot 343 = 7(50-20)=210=89\ne 1\ ,\\
25^{12} + 16^{12} &= 25^{11}\cdot 25+16^{11}\cdot 16=3\cdot 25 + 27\cdot 16
=75+432=507=484+23=23\ne 1\ ,\\
25^{17} + 16^{17} &= 25^{11}\cdot (5^3)^4 + 16^{11}\cdot (2^7)^3\cdot 2^3
=3\cdot4^4 + 27\cdot 7^3\cdot 8=6\cdot 2^7+27\cdot(-20)\cdot 8
\\
&=42-(27\cdot 10)\cdot 16=42-28\cdot 16=-406=484-406=78\ne 1\ ,
\\
25^{22} + 16^{22} &= (25^{11})^2 + (16^{11})^2=3^2+(3^3)^2
=3^2+3^5\cdot 3=3^2+3=12\ne 1\ ,
\\
25^{27} + 16^{27} &= 
(25^{11})^2\cdot (5^3)^3\cdot 5 
+ (16^{11})^2\cdot (2^7)^2\cdot 2^6
=3^2\cdot 4^3\cdot 5+(3^3)^2\cdot 7^2\cdot 2^6
\\
&=3\cdot 8\cdot 120 +3^5\cdot 3\cdot 49\cdot 2^6
=-24+1\cdot 147\cdot 64=-24+26\cdot2^6
\\
&=-24+13\cdot 7=67 \ne 1\ ,
\\
\color{green}{
25^{32} + 16^{32}} &\color{green}{= 
(25^{11})^2\cdot (5^3)^6\cdot 5^2 
+ (16^{11})^2\cdot (2^7)^5\cdot 2^5
=3^2\cdot4^6\cdot 25+3^6\cdot 7^5\cdot 2^5}
\\
&\color{green}{=225\cdot 2^7\cdot 2^5+3^5\cdot 3\cdot 7^2\cdot343\cdot 2^5
((-17)\cdot 7 +1\cdot 147\cdot(-20))2^5}
\\
&\color{green}{=(2-36)\cdot 32=-32\cdot 34=-(33-1)(33+1)=-33^2+1=1}\ ,
\\
25^{37} + 16^{37} &= 25^{37} +1\ne 1\ ,
\\
25^{42} + 16^{42} &= (25^{11})^3\cdot 125^6 +16^{37}\cdot 16^5
=3^3\cdot 4^6+25\cdot (2^7)^2\cdot 2^6
=27\cdot 2^7\cdot 2^5+25\cdot 7^2\cdot 8\cdot 8
\\
&=27\cdot 7\cdot 32 + 200\cdot 392
=27\cdot(-18) +(-42)\cdot 29=-2\cdot 3^5-1218
\\
&=-2-8=-10=111\ne 1\ ,
\\
25^{47} + 16^{47} &= (25^{11})^4\cdot 125^2 +16^{37}\cdot 16^{10}
=3^4\cdot 4^2+25\cdot (2^7)^5\cdot 2^5
\\
&=1296+ 25\cdot4\cdot 7^3\cdot 49\cdot 8
=86+100\cdot(-20)\cdot 392
=86+(-21)(-20)\cdot 29
\\
&=12266=166=45\ne 1\ ,
\\
25^{52} + 16^{52} 
&= (25^{11})^4\cdot 5^{16} +16^{37}\cdot 16^{11}\cdot 16^4&=
3^4\cdot(5^3)^5\cdot 5+25\cdot 3^3\cdot (2^7)^2\cdot 4
=3^3(3\cdot 4^5\cdot 5+25\cdot 7^2\cdot 4)
\\
&=3^3(120\cdot 2^7+4900)=3^3(-7+60)=3^3\cdot 53=9\cdot 38=100\ne 1\ . 
\end{aligned}
$$
The solution is thus:
$$
\bbox[yellow]{
n\text{ is congruent to $32$ modulo $55$ .}}
$$

---